# Independent-samples t-test on the "Gain Scores" from two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, interaction, pre-post-comparison

I have a simple Pre-Test Post-Test Control design like this:

[image]

where, $R$ = Random Assignment to groups;
$O$ = Observation;
$T$ = Treatment;
$C$ = Control.

A colleague suggested that by doing and *independent-samples t-test* between the Gain Scores (i.e., $Posttest - Pretest$) of the two groups, I am actually looking at the *interaction effect in a two-way design*.

## Question:

I am wondering how there could exist an interaction effect in such a design?

My colleague says: "*You start with two groups, one of which will receive treatment. This is the first factor with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Then you measure them again, with one group receiving treatment, the second factor with means $\mu_3$ and $\mu_4$. No interaction is $\mu_1-\mu_3=\mu_2-\mu_4$*.

*You can plot this by putting: x-axis first two groups, y-axis means, the two lines corresponding to the second factor.*"

Comment: what is the logic given by him for interaction effect ? and what is the reason you do not agree with his opinion ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar, I updated my question. I basically can't understand my colleagues comment regarding how to think of this design as an interaction effect and even how to plot this as an interaction plot?

Comment: @subhashc.davar, could you now better understand OP's question?

Comment: It is difficult to contemplate what is beng considered as interaction ? interaction between groups or relatedness of subjects in the treatment and control group etc. And how do you  estimate interactions either mathematically or statistically.